# Remove duplicated values from the values in a row i sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My input code is like,

```
Emp_ID       Scenarios
10902543     SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4
11083080     SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3
10988779     SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 3
```

and want output should be,

```
Emp_ID       Scenarios
10902543    SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4
11083080    SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3
10988779    SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 3
```

Need to do it without while loop, can you please suggest any other alternative.

Comment: Yes. First, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is **Absolutly yes!**.
Second, read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/).

Comment: Please share your sql query.

Comment: select * from ##SCENARIOS_BASE

EMP_ID        COMMENTS
10016351 SCENARIO 4
10016351 SCENARIO 1
10016351 SCENARIO 4
10016351 SCENARIO 4
10048404 SCENARIO 3
10684877 SCENARIO 1
10048404 SCENARIO 1

SELECT  EMP_ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(COMMENTS AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM ##SCENARIOS_BASE 
         WHERE EMP_ID = T.EMP_ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM ##SCENARIOS_BASE T 
GROUP BY EMP_ID

Answer (score 2):

First use a `SplitString` function, then `Distinct` scenario value, and finally join them by `For xml path` + `STUFF`

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
 Emp_ID int,
 Scenarios varchar(200)   
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    Emp_ID,
    Scenarios
)
VALUES
( 10902543, 'SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4'),
( 11083080, 'SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3'),
( 10988779, 'SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 3')

SELECT sd.Emp_ID, s.Scenarios
FROM @SampleData sd
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF((  
                SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ s.Value
                FROM [dbo].[SplitString](sd.Scenarios, ',') s
                FOR XML PATH('')
             )
    , 1,2,'') AS Scenarios

) s
```

Split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] (@Text varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
   Select Pos = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
        ,Value = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
   From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@Text,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
   Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Returns

```
Emp_ID      Scenarios
-----------------------------------------------
10902543    SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 4
11083080    SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3
10988779    SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 4
```

Comment: I was just starting to write an answer very much like yours... +1. Just one thing, the `stuff` function doesn't join them, that's the `for xml path('')`. All the `stuff` does is remove the first comma.

Comment: If you use XML make sure you are accounting for <, >, &

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing with XML methods

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB(Emp_ID BIGINT, Scenarios VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #TAB

SELECT 10902543,'SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4'
UNION ALL
SELECT 11083080,'SCENARIO 3, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 10988779,'SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 1, SCENARIO 4, SCENARIO 3'
```

Now Split Scenarios, apply Distinct & add them together with comma.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT Emp_ID,  SPLT.B.value('.','varchar(max)') Scenarios 
    FROM(
        SELECT Emp_ID, Scenarios
        ,CAST( '<M>'+REPLACE(Scenarios,', ','</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) XML_DATA
        FROM #TAB
    )A
    CROSS APPLY
    A.XML_DATA.nodes('/M') AS SPLT(B)
)
SELECT DISTINCT Emp_ID
, STUFF((SELECT ','+Scenarios
FROM CTE C1 
WHERE C1.Emp_ID = C2.Emp_ID FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'') as Scenarios FROM CTE C2
```

**Result:**

```
+----------+----------------------------------+
|  Emp_ID  |            Scenarios             |
+----------+----------------------------------+
| 10902543 | SCENARIO 1,SCENARIO 3,SCENARIO 4 |
| 10988779 | SCENARIO 1,SCENARIO 3,SCENARIO 4 |
| 11083080 | SCENARIO 1,SCENARIO 3            |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```